# Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P^2\sharp \mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-extensions

Note that $ \langle a,b|a^2b^{-1}a^{-2} b \rangle =\pi_1 ( X):=G$ where $X=\mathbb{R}P^2\sharp \mathbb{R}P^2$.

So $a^2,\ b$ commute in $G$ so that $G$ contains $H:=\mathbb{Z}^2$.

In further note that $[H:G]=2$. That is $G$ may be a semi-direct between $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or a free product. $H$ is a normal subgroup ? Thank you in advace.

Comment: What do you think the universal covering space of $X$ is?

Comment: I see. Thank you. It is $\mathbb{R}^2$. And $X$ is Klein bottle, which is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-quotient of torus.

Comment: Are you sure that you got the correct presentation for the group?  If it were $\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b\rangle$, I would believe the subgroup generated by $a^2,b$ is an index-two subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$. In any case, index-two subgroups (written $[G:H]=2$) are always normal.

Comment: You are right. (1) For $X:=\mathbb{R}P^2\sharp \mathbb{R}P^2$, $\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b,c|a^2b^{-1}c^2 b \rangle$ (2) My question : What is $\langle a,b|a^2 ba^{-2}b^{-1}\rangle$

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to know what it is beyond curiosity?  A lot of times it seems the group presentation *is* what the group is.  I don't believe $H$ is normal (I was constructing a Schreier graph of the cosets of $H$ and the symmetry was not transitive), but I also don't think the group is simply a free product.

Comment: There's one thing I can say: the center of the group you are interested in seems to be generated by $a^2$.  The quotient of the group by the center is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, so it is a central extension of a free product of cyclic groups by $\mathbb{Z}$, if I've gotten this right.

Comment: You may be right. Now I agree that presentation is the $sufficient$ answer for a problem calculating the fundamental group of space in illustration in basic topology book.

Comment: What $\sharp$ means?